# What is the technical details behind the JWplayer that IDM does not start downloading?

Tags: http-live-streaming, jwplayer, video.js, idm

It seems that Internet download manager (IDM) does not start downloading [streaming vdieo through JWplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/web-player-demos/adaptive-streaming/) (which are in fact small `.ts` files).

I thought it is becaue IDM is not working with `.ts` or small files so tried converting a sample mp4 into small `.ts` files and created a m3u8 and tried playing the video using [video.js](https://videojs.com/) but IDM starts downloading a big ts file which merged all parts.

Is there a special technical protection in JWplayer or there is copyright or something else? Why IDM starts downloading when using `video.js` and not starts when using JWplayer?

this is sample m3u8 I used:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence0.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence2.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence3.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence4.ts
#EXTINF:6.000000,
fileSequence5.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

and this is how I tried playing with video.js

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<video class="video-js" width="1280" height="720" data-setup='{}' controls>
        <source src="prog_index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
<script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js'></script>
```

Comment: This all seems like expected behavior to me. What is not working the way you think it should, and how do you think it should work?

Comment: Why IDM starts downloading `.ts` files when I use `video.js` and not starts downloading when using jwplayer? @szatmary

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Internet downlaod manager won't start automatically when the website uses HTTPS instead of HTTP. After installing SSL both **Video.js** and **Jwplayer** are working same.